# how to detect voice messages on whatsapp with whatsapp-web.js

Tags: message, whatsapp, voice

how to detect voice messages on whatsapp with whatsapp-web.js

I tried this but it seems like it doesn't work
client.on('voice', async (msg) => {}

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a project that saves the various types of files/content sent to my phone which is connected to whatsapp-web.js library.
I suggest you test the solution with some logs on the incoming message type.

**You could solve this problem directly from the message reply (msg):**

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
   if(msg.type == 'ptt'){
      // is a voice message
   }
});
```

**also with the mimetype of downloadMedia():**

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
   if(msg.hasMedia) {
      const media = await msg.downloadMedia();
      var mmtype = media.mimetype;
      if(media.mimetype.contains('audio/ogg')){
         // is a voice message
         // don't know if .contains() is the solution try other comparators
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (msg.type == 'ptt') {
    console.log("Voice Clip Received");

    const media = await msg.downloadMedia().
        then((data) => {

            const binaryData = Buffer.from(data.data, 'base64');
            fs.writeFile('audio.ogg', binaryData, function (err) {
            })
        });      
}
```